# Setup Android spinner to navigate to another page

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, spinner

I am very new to Android apps.

I have a spinner setup with, what will be a lot of different options.

Can you please help me?

I need to open a new page with each different spinner option.

How do I do this?

Code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="top"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinner1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
  android:entries="@array/model_numbers"
  android:prompt="@string/model_spinner" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:text="Please select model number below:"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:text="peter.gosling@email.com"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
  android:text="Version 1.0"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.capitaokipartslist;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
}

}
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Capita Oki Parts List</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="model_number">Please select your model number:</string>
<string name="model_spinner">Please select your model number:</string>
<string-array name="model_numbers">
  <item >C711</item>
  <item >ES7411</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

Please go throw these tutorials

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

http://androidexample.com/Spinner_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=82&aaid=105

http://androidituts.com/android-spinner-tutorial/

Inside your onItemSelected method pass intent

```
Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,Myclass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

**UPDATE**

As you asked to go on different activity so you can use if or switch apply conditions and move accordingly.

Ex:-

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
    "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
switch(pos)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,Myclass1.class);
    startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,Myclass2.class);
    startActivity(i);
                }

  }
```

Here CurrentActivity is Your current Activity name from which you want to navigate and Myclass1 and Myclass2 is your that class where you wants to go.

There are another methods whivh may help you like :

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
```

Comment: These tutorials just show the selection onscreen - so how do I change it so it opens a new page? Thanks for you help

Comment: Have you find the onItemSelected  method in these tutorials. a Toast method is written to print message. If you dont want toast just remove it and use that Two lines of coding which i pasted above.

Comment: I got it to display the message using TOAST.  and have now replaced the toast method with the Intent method you posted above..... As I need a different activity to open with each different option how do I reference this - as Myclass is a single activity? so would be the same page with each different option??

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something along these lines, in onCreate method;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String [] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.model_numbers);
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.a_layout, array));
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewClass.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherClass.class));
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: in MainActivity, onCreate method, after setContentView().

Comment: @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}  SOMEWHERE HERE?

Comment: seem to get a few errors on the left and side of the MainActivity.java when inputting this? i.e. VIEW CANNOT BE RESOLVED TO TYPE, SPIN CANNOT BE RESOLVED, ONITEMSELECTEDLISTENER CANNOT BE RESOLVED TO A TYPE, SPIN CANNOT BE RESOLVED, A_LAYOUT CANNOT BE RESOLVED OR IS NOT A FIELD, SPIN CANNOT BE RESOLVED TO A VARIABLE, SPINNER CANNOT BE RESOLVED OR IS NOT A FIELD, SPINNER CANNOT BE RESOLVED TO A TYPE??

Comment: Don't want to sound harsh, but you might want to do some reading to get the core fundamentals down first before attempting to write code.